# Can splot command create data blocks through "set table"?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a 2D function and I print out the multicolumn data generated by set table after a splot f(x,y) command.

```
gnuplot>f(x,y)=sin(x*y)
> set table "isocurve.dat"
> splot [-pi:pi] [-pi:pi] f(x,y)
```

Data blocks representing isocurves are separted by a single empty line in the Ascii file generated by set table.

Hence the data file consists only of one block.

Question is: Is it possible to get the isocurves separated by two empty lines so that they can be tracked as data blocks?

I find it interesting because that would allow you to get simple statistics of individual isocurves using the stats command. As an example:

```
set print 'max.dat'
do for [i=0:10]{
stats 'isocurve.dat' u 1:3 index i
print i,STAS_pos_max_y,STATS_max}
```

As a workaround it is possible to pipe the isocurve.dat file through awk and get empty lines doubles. But I am just asking if gnuplot can do that on its own.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `plot for ...` to simulate `splot`, then iterations are saved as separate data blocks:

```
N = 21
set table 'table.dat'
plot for [i=0:(N-1)] f(x, i*pi*(2.0/N) - pi)
unset table
```

Although that works, it is not the kind of task I would use gnuplot for.

Comment: Thank you. Also I could use splot to generate the table the standard way; and later this kind of iteration to perform the stats on each isocurve.